# How to map the latest child of a collection with JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a `Product` entity class and I want it to join with the `Price` table.

My goal is to persist the old prices for reporting and when I get the `Product` entity it should be mapped with latest price according to the latest date.

Please explain me how I can achieve this in Hibernate JPA relation. If possible share a code snippet.

Answer (score 7):

Your domain module can use [`@JoinFormula`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-the-latest-child-of-a-parent-entity-using-hibernate-joinformula/), like this:

```
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "product", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Price> prices = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinFormula(
        "(SELECT id FROM price ORDER BY created_on DESC LIMIT 1)"
    )
    private Price latestPrice;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Price> getPrices() {
        return prices;
    }

    public void addPrice(BigDecimal priceValue) {
        Price price = new Price();
        price.setPrice(priceValue);
        prices.add(price);
        price.setProduct(this);
        latestPrice = price;
    }
    
    public Price getLatestPrice() {
        return latestPrice;
    }
}

@Entity(name = "Price")
public class Price {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Product product;
    
    @Column(name = "created_on", nullable=false, updatable=false)
    private Date createdOn;

    private BigDecimal price;

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    
    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        createdOn = new Date();        
    }
}
```

This is how you'd update a Product's price:

```
Long id = ...;
BigDecimal newPriceValue = ...;

Product product = entityManager.find(Product, id);
Price oldPrice = product.getLatestPrice();    

product.addPrice(newPriceValue);
```

Comment: I saw you just added the `DESC`, but I think you also need to put the select statement into parenthesis

Comment: Sure. I realized that without DESC, I wouldn't return the latest entry, but the first one. I also added the parenthesis as you suggested.

Comment: @VladMihalcea Can you please why the `latestPrice` attribute annotated with `@ManyToOne`?

Comment: Because this is a to-one relation. Both `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToOne` should work.

Comment: vote this annotation @LastEllementCollection: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14696

Answer (score 1):

I really like the answer of @vlad-mihalcea, unfortunately I also need to support Oracle. I ended up with a less elegant solution but it works with Oracle:

```java
...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinFormula(
        "(SELECT p.id FROM price p WHERE p.product_id = id and p.created_on = (select max(p2.created_on) from price p2 where p2.product_id = id))"
    )
    private Price latestPrice;
...
```